# C++ how to pass method as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, hash, unordered-map

Suppose I have a class `X`:

```
class X {
    // ...
    size_t hash() const { return ...; }
};
```

I would like to create a `std::tr1::unordered_map<X, int, HashFn>` where I want to pass in
`X::hash()` as `HashFn`. I know I can declare my own functor object. I feel that
there should be a way to do this by directly passing a pointer to `X::hash()`.

Is there?

Comment: You should be able to as long as you declare the function static, if it's not static - which instance of `X` will it use? Ergo, if it's static, why not make it a free function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; as you've shown it, you need a small utility struct:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T, std::size_t (T::*HashFunc)() const = &T::hash>
struct hasher : std::unary_function<T, std::size_t>
{
    std::size_t operator ()(T const& t) const
    {
        return (t.*HashFunc)();
    }
};
```

Then you can create an `unordered_map` like so:

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<X, int, hasher<X> > m;
```

Comment: Thanks. Any particular reason why we need the operator to be const w.r.t struct hasher. Why can't hasher have state ?

Comment: @user231536 : The C++0x draft has a specific requirement for hash functors: in the expression `h(k)` where `h` is a hash functor, "*The value returned shall depend only on the argument `k`.*" This implies that state wouldn't be generally useful inside a hash functor. I assume the same hash requirements apply to TR1 as to C++0x.

Comment: @user231536 : Also, reading over the requirements again, it says "*Given `h` is a value of type (possibly `const`) `H`, ...*", which would imply that `operator()` would need to be `const`.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.  The reason is that whatever is used as your HashFn must take a single argument which is a const reference to an object in the container.  `X::hash` takes a single argument which is a const *pointer* to an object in the container (the `this` pointer is an implicit first argument in this case), so using that function by it self is not possible.

You probably use some bind magic, using boost::lambda and boost::bind.  I'm not exactly sure how, but it would probably look something like this:

```
boost::bind(&X::hash, &_1);
```

Which creates a function object which will call X::hash with a pointer.

Comment: In the general case, it's not possible to know the result type of `boost::bind` for use as the third template argument to `unordered_map`.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t hash() const { return ...;}
```

A function which calculates hash value takes one parameter of type `Key` which your function doesn't take. Hence its signature is wrong to begin with.

Since you want to implement a function, rather than a functor, here is how it should be done:

```
size_t hash(const KeyType &key) 
{
    return /*calculate hash and return it*/;
}
```

Make it `static` member  function and pass it as `X::hash` or make it a free function, is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly, but you can wrap it. The easy way to do so is to use `boost::mem_fn()`, or the standard equivalents if your compiler supports them: `tr1::mem_fn()` (from TR1) or `std::mem_fn()` (from C++11).

EDIT: Actually it's not so simple. `mem_fn()` will work fine for a function parameter, but since its return type is unspecified it's difficult to use as a template parameter. If you have C++11 support you could use `decltype` to find the type; otherwise you're probably best off writing your own function object as you mentioned.